# How to get firebase analytics to work on Android (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

So I have followed the following guides:
1. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/installation/initial-setup
2. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/installation/android
3. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/analytics/android

I got the build to work, but I do not see any activity in the firebase console? Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: can you see active users? if not then your setup is missing something. if you can see active users etc and not seeing crashes then try some force crash method

Comment: You should be able to see users after 20/40 mins. Of course, you need to build the app and open it in either an emulator or on real device